# Trying to create link between AutoCAD and mySQL to auto-complete other attributes

Tags: mysql, database, excel, autocad

I am sure this is a tall order but I have to ask. How would I go about creating link between AutoCAD 2012 and mySQL to when defining a block attribute in AutoCAD it updates several other attributes based on a cross reference to a mySQL database.

I tried to find another question like this but was unable to do so. If I missed it please link.

If you need any clarification, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could also use Excel if that would make it easier.

Comment: Autodesk tries to work well with Excel and other Microsoft products.  Do you prefer to create an external application in Excel that looks at AutoCAD, or would you like to create a command or menu item inside AutoCAD, or would you like to create reactors inside AutoCAD.  Most of this stuff is outside my realm of expertise and experience, but I may be able to give you a leg up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Map3D or civil3D you can connect to external databases to do some work.

if you want to use only AutoCAD 
I think you may need to create a plugin to do that using .NET C#.

or you can use Excel to fetch attribute to the dwg and make excel update from mySQL database.